# CSS selector for selecting an alternating element group

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have an HTML table that I want to highlight alternating groups of 3 rows such that rows 0-3 are highlighted, rows 4-6 are not, rows 7-9 are highlighted, etc.

The best solution I've come up with so far is:

```
tr:nth-child(6n + 1),
tr:nth-child(6n + 2),
tr:nth-child(6n + 3) {
   background-color:#eee;
}
```

Is is possible to condense these selectors into a single selector?

Comment: +1 for a good question, although to be honest, I don't think your existing solution is that bad.

Comment: It's not too bad when you're only doing 3 rows at a time, but 10 (which is what I'm actually doing on the site) starts to look ugly.  My brain sees the essentially copy/paste code and immediately screams, "there's got to be a better way!"  :)

Comment: Fair enough. But if we're talking about groups of ten table rows at a time being linked, I have to question whether the table structure you've got is semantically correct in the first place. I haven't seen the data, so I can't really say for certain, but it does sound like there might be better ways to structure the HTML.

Comment: I agree with your assessment, however in this case the rows aren't semantically linked.  The highlighting is just a visual design decision that, I assume, is intended to make the table easier to visually scan.

Comment: Hmm, well in that case, I'd go back to my first comment, and suggest sticking with your existing solution. It may look ugly, but it's the most semantically correct answer. Either that or revert to using class names. The [`nth-child` syntax](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#nth-child-pseudo) doesn't offer anything more concise for what you want, but if you want to you can try out some ideas here: http://css-tricks.com/examples/nth-child-tester.

Answer (score 2):

### Yes, its possible in a single selector (but is it best???)

If doing it in groups of ten (as your comment says is your *ultimate* goal) it may not be worth doing as opposed to having the ten individual selectors, as the individual selectors will probably be more clear.

**Groups of Three ([see fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bLu69/22/))**

```
tr:not(:nth-child(6n+4)):not(:nth-child(6n+5)):not(:nth-child(6n+6)) {
    background-color: #eee;
}
```

**Groups of Ten ([see fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bLu69/23/))**

```
tr:not(:nth-child(20n+11)):not(:nth-child(20n+12)):not(:nth-child(20n+13)):not(:nth-child(20n+14)):not(:nth-child(20n+15)):not(:nth-child(20n+16)):not(:nth-child(20n+17)):not(:nth-child(20n+18)):not(:nth-child(20n+19)):not(:nth-child(20n+20)) {
    background-color: #eee;
}
```

This obviously does not eliminate your copy/paste of code issue you hoped to avoid, and questionable as to whether it qualifies as "condensed." However, it is reduced to a single selector.

Answer (score 1):

If your rows are being styled this way because there is a relationship between them, then grouping them using the `<tbody>` element is appropriate here and would trim down your selector.

http://codepen.io/cimmanon/pen/KqoCs

```
tbody:nth-child(odd) {
  background: #CCC;
}

<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td rowspan="3"></td>
            <td>a</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>b</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>c</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>

    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td rowspan="3"></td>
            <td>a</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>b</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>c</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>

    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td rowspan="3"></td>
            <td>a</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>b</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>c</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

If this is purely a case of *I don't really want to type out all of these selectors by hand*, you could use a CSS Preprocessor to generate them for you.

http://codepen.io/cimmanon/pen/Hrimz

Sass:

```
@mixin fat-zebra($rows) {
  $collector: ();
  @for $r from 1 through $rows {
    $collector: append($collector, unquote("&:nth-child(#{$rows * 2}n+#{$r})"), comma);
  }
  #{$collector} {
    @content;
  }
}

td {
    @include fat-zebra(3) {
        background: yellow;
    }
}
```

Output:

```
td:nth-child(6n+1), td:nth-child(6n+2), td:nth-child(6n+3) {
  background: yellow;
}
```

More rows?

```
td {
    @include fat-zebra(10) {
        background: yellow;
    }
}
```

Output:

```
td:nth-child(20n+1), td:nth-child(20n+2), td:nth-child(20n+3), td:nth-child(20n+4), td:nth-child(20n+5), td:nth-child(20n+6), td:nth-child(20n+7), td:nth-child(20n+8), td:nth-child(20n+9), td:nth-child(20n+10) {
  background: yellow;
}
```